# Showing JSON API data in UI

Tags: android, json, api, cardview

I'm trying to show the result of my request but it executes the request at the end.
you can see the logs.

I tried 3 different ways

1 - Create a subclass that extends BaseAdapter
2 - Create a RecycleView.AdapterView
3 - AsyncTask (to run the request before "rendering the UI" if that's correct)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

JSONArray result = new JSONArray();

TextView name, phone, location;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    name = findViewById(R.id.name);
    phone = findViewById(R.id.phone);
    location = findViewById(R.id.location);
    Log.i("MainActivity","finished with TextViews");

    new MyTask().execute(url);
}

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray> {

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {

        Log.i("MainActivity","starting with doInBackground");
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        String url = params[0];
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        result = response;

                        Log.i("MainActivity",result.toString());
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        error.printStackTrace();
                        result.put(error.toString());

                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> token = new HashMap<>();
                token.put("Authorization", "Token *************");
                return token;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
        Log.i("MainActivity", "finished with doInBackground");
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i("MainActivity","stating with onPostExecute");
        // do something with result

        for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
            try {
                name.setText(new JSONObject(result.get(i).toString()).get("seller_name").toString());
                phone.setText(new JSONObject(result.get(i).toString()).get("seller_phone").toString());
                location.setText(new JSONObject(result.get(i).toString()).get("seller_location").toString());
            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                name.setText("Error");
                phone.setText("Error");
                location.setText("Error");

            }
        }

        Log.i("MainActivity","finished with onPostExecute");
    }
}

public JSONArray doSomeWork(String url_) {

    Log.i("MainActivity","starting with doSomeWork");

    return result;
}}
```

Logs:

MainActivity: finished with TextViews

MainActivity: starting with doInBackground

MainActivity: finished with doInBackground

MainActivity: stating with onPostExecute

MainActivity: finished with onPostExecute

MainActivity: data returned from the onResponse method - JSON

Comment: You don't need `AsyncTask ` for `Volley` call as request is handled in separate worker thread not on UI thread

Comment: okay, then how can I show the data from the request to the UI, from what I figure out the request needs to be done first so i can render the data in the ui, if that's correct how can i do that?

Comment: I've added the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**  Main issue with your approach is that you're making Asynchronous call inside another Asynchronous call and expecting synchronous result. Thats why result is empty because inner Asynchronous call hasn't finished yet.

**Solution:** You can resolve this by removing `AsyncTask` altogether as Volley run in separate worker thread by-default.

You can do some thing like this

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        name = findViewById(R.id.name);
        phone = findViewById(R.id.phone);
        location = findViewById(R.id.location);
        Log.i("MainActivity","finished with TextViews");

        doSomeWork(url);
    }


    private void doSomeWork(String url) {

        Log.i("MainActivity","starting with doSomeWork");

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        renderUI(response);
                        Log.i("MainActivity",result.toString());
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        error.printStackTrace();

                        result.put(error.toString());
                        renderUI(result);

                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> token = new HashMap<>();
                token.put("Authorization", "Token *************");
                return token;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

 private void renderUI(JSONArray result) {

         for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
                try {
                    name.setText(new JSONObject(result.get(i).toString()).get("seller_name").toString());
                    phone.setText(new JSONObject(result.get(i).toString()).get("seller_phone").toString());
                    location.setText(new JSONObject(result.get(i).toString()).get("seller_location").toString());
                }catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    name.setText("Error");
                    phone.setText("Error");
                    location.setText("Error");

                }
            }
 }
```

**Note:** Also the way you're populating the UI directly from response is not very efficient. You can use a model class with [Gson library](https://github.com/google/gson) for parsing purpose.

Cheers :)

Comment: And i should add, using Retrofit instead of the async tasks will also be good.